# how to remove the Loadingrow event programatically in silverlight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0

how to remove the Loadingrow event programatically in silverlight Datagrid
or I need to deactivate the event after it is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Only make this after bind your datagrid:

```
datagrid1.EventName -= YourEventName;
```